# How to stop double cursors from appearing?

Tags: lubuntu, cursor, multipointerx

Whenever I try to drag and drop something, my cursor may split into two cursors or one cursor with two arrows! I can't seem to take a screenshot ..

I'm able to make it stop without locking the screen .. but I don't want it to appear all of a sudden. Is there a solution to prevent it from happening? I'm using Lubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Same here. Only the left hand one is active

Comment: I suggest upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu. If the problem persists, edit your question. 14.10 is already obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

it's an old thread but if trying the code above, new gsettings is in this format:

```
gsettings set "SCHEMA" "KEY" "VALUE"
```

so will be the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings.daemon-plugins.cursor active false
```

i have always hated how gnome renders the double cursor or cursor over cursor.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this from the terminal and enter this in:

```
 gsettings org.gnome.settings.daemon-plugins.cursor -KEY=active -VALUE=false
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I get this:

Usage:
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE

Set the value of KEY to VALUE

Arguments:
  SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
  SCHEMA    The name of the schema
  PATH      The path, for relocatable schemas
  KEY       The key within the schema
  VALUE     The value to set

Comment: If something doesn't work for you, don't downvote it! It might for for others, and downvotes should only be used for unclear/unrelated anwsers

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue only in firefox.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1187719

Taking screenshots (import, shutter) and recording videos (recordmydesktop) grab the cursor as it should look, although I see it doubled on screen.

Try displaying any image file with some image viewer. In my case "qiv" image browser solves the problem until next X11 start.

I'm using 14.04.

Comment: I upgraded to 15.04 and it seems it solved the problem